# Binaries for android FFmpeg and SOX

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, sox, android-ffmpeg

I have been trying for two weeks to find binaries for ffmpeg and Sox (armeabi,armeabiv7, x86) but i did not succeed. I tried building it my self from [this project](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg) but I still [did not succeed](https://gist.github.com/kcochibili/bedb80eb405870faa1a657b2e8e94550). 
Can you help me build the project and then share the binaries?

I would heartly appreciate.
Here is the github repository
https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

Comment: what do you mean you didn't succeed? Did you cross compile with arm-toolchain using NDK? If so, can you post the compilation log?

Comment: @mdasari I encountered errors while building it myself. I am new to building native binaries, so I do not know what you mean by cross compiling with arm-toolchain. but I did follow all the instructions of building it. here is my build log: https://gist.github.com/kcochibili/bedb80eb405870faa1a657b2e8e94550

Comment: I see some issues link there is no working 'c compiler' and no config.h file.. etc.. and I don't think you posted complete log. If all you need is binaries for android, I can give but if you need source too.. you need to setup the arm-c compiler properly.

Comment: @mdasari The Git bash terminates before I am able to copy the whole whole log. All I need is the binaries for android, I would appreciate if you can give me that.

Comment: @mdasari Yes, the binaries is all I need, can you give me that?

Comment: You can find binaries here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxBwaoy1IbRXSDZURTZpNGt4NXM

Comment: @mdasari Thank you, but the binaries I need should be of types  (armeabi,armeabiv7, x86) to support different device architecture, and should have PIE support. the binary you provided did not work on my galaxy s8. Can you build from the github repository on my question?github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg
it includes FFmpeg and SOX, and is configured to support PIE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two libraries ultimately did it for me:

For FFMPEG (Video editing library):
https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/android

For SOX (Sound editing library):
https://github.com/kcochibili/SoxLibraryForAndroid

The binaries are in the corresponding links.

Answer (score 1):

The project you asked has broken submodules, just update them and build with NDK 9d, and your binaries will build flawlessly.

I was using this other project - https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java - but it's almost the same, here are the instructions:

1) git submodule update --init

2) Update .git/modules/external/android-ffmpeg with this code:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    worktree = ../../../../external/android-ffmpeg
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[submodule "ffmpeg"]
    url = http://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg.git
[submodule "freetype2"]
    url = http://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/freetype/freetype2.git/
[submodule "sox"]
    url = https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java.git
[submodule "x264"]
    url = http://git.videolan.org/git/x264.git
```

3) Point the NDK_BASE to android ndk 9d, you can download here http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

4) Follow build instructions on repo

Comment: Can you share your built binaries?

Comment: Sorry I can't, I'm under a company.

Comment: Tears dripping... Anyways, I appreciate your detailed solution. Thank you.  I will give it a shot if I must spend more time on this.

Comment: If you face any issue, just warn me here

Comment: @RaphaelAdamski: These submodules seems to be broken. If you can update them...it will be a great help. TIA